# How to create a test module to test an Android library in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, intellij-idea

I created an Android Library, but when I try to create an Android Test Module, the **Tested module** combobox has only a red **[none]**, I cannot select the library itself.

Do I need to purposely create an Android application just to test the library?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I asked in JetBrains forum and got this [reply](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/450600;jsessionid=9434F614058BF1CB05C9699C1D4D1EBA):

> Currently there is no way to create test module
>   for library module automatically. You can, for example, create
>   application module that depends on the library module, and then create
>   test module for it. Another way is to put the instrumentation into the
>   application module itself, so additional "test" module is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

"Tested module" is where your library supposed to be.

IntelliJ documentation: [Testing Android Applications](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/testing-android-applications.html)

Comment: The problem is there is nothing to select in "Tested module" other than the red "[none]". Nevertheless, I have asked in Jetbrains forum and got a reply. Please see my answer for this question.